# For loop ignoring directories with a space in them?

Tags: batch-file

Currently, my simple batch script looks like this:

```
@echo off
for /D /r C:\myprojects\AIS\ %%G in (_svn) do rd /S /Q %%G
pause
```

Unfortunately, this skips any directories with a space character in them, such as a directory called "My Projects".  How do I get around this and make sure I traverse that directory as well?

Comment: is this Windows (DOS)? perhaps a 'batch-file' tag

Comment: Yes it is.  I put the "batch" tag on it, but I'll also include "batch-file" if you'd like.

Comment: sorry, didn't see that, brain dead on a Friday morning

Comment: No worries :)  I've added it anyways, to keep things specific.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... it seems to work for me. Have you tried echo instead?

```
C:\tmp> TREE /A C:\tmp\xxx
C:\TMP\XXX
\---one one
    \---two two

C:\tmp> FOR /D /R c:\tmp\xxx %I IN (_svn) DO @ECHO RD "%I"
RD "c:\tmp\xxx\_svn"
RD "c:\tmp\xxx\one one\_svn"
RD "c:\tmp\xxx\one one\two two\_svn"
```

You probably need quotes around your argument to `rmdir`.  If you want to be truly paranoid, then use `%~I` instead to protect against the chaos that `FOR /D /R ... %I IN ("_svn")` would otherwise cause.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put quotes around the directory name?

Comment: I tried this: for /D /r C:\electionscanadaprojects\AIS\ "%%G" in (_svn) do rd /S /Q "%%G", since %%G holds the directory name, but no dice.

Comment: Do you have to escape the quotes somehow?  I'm just guessing here, I'm not a DOS guy (this is DOS, right?)

Comment: Yes it is dos.  I don't believe you have to escape the quotes, as this normally works if you've given the direct path to the directory.  However, it being stored in a variable is causing me issues, I think.  (I'm knew to batch scripting.  May be wrong)

Comment: So this is no good, right?  
for /D /r C:\electionscanadaprojects\AIS\ \"%%G\" in (_svn) do rd /S /Q "%%G"

Comment: A quick guess, shouldn't the quotes just be around the second instance of %%G, and not around the first one?

Comment: That would make too much sense.